# Feature Event Receiver activation, application page set as default newform

Tags: feature-activation, application-pages, layouts

I am trying to set the application page as default.
So I have added an application page in `layouts` folder using visual studio.
But when I run the code in feature activation I am trying to get the file in layouts folder

```
Spfile form = web.GetFile("_layouts/filename");
```

But if I check `if(form.exists)`
It fails the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the feature is activated we access the default content type in the “Demo List” list which is “Item” , we save it’s default forms urls as custom web properties so we can recover them when we need to do so. Then we access once again the “Item” content type to define its forms url’s using the customs forms urls this time. For more Details check URL" https://achrafsp.wordpress.com/tag/programmatically-provisioning-list-custom-forms/

You can also find code for this in above article.

Also if you are creating list using Visual Studio then in List defination also you can specify custom application pages present in layout folder. You can also check for this in above url.

Comment: Awesome.. Worked perfectly for me..

Comment: @Avinash: Glad to hear that..:)

Answer (score 0):

For accessing layout folder (which is in the file system) you should use a different approach.

For 2013

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getversionedgenericsetuppath.aspx

For 2010 `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath`

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Its giving me an error while deploying..